# How to return a string in Clojure

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, return

I'm very new to Clojure and functional programming.  I am working on Codewars "Even or Odd" practice question.
My desired result is to return "Even" or "Odd" given the passed in argument.
My code so far simply prints the word "Even" or "Odd."

```
(ns kata)

(defn even-or-odd [number]
  ; ...
   (if (= (Math/abs (rem number 2)) 1)
    (println "Odd")
    (println "Even"))
)
```

My tests are failing with this message: `expected: (= (even-or-odd 2) "Even") actual: (not (= nil "Even"))`

How do I return the word "Even" or "Odd" instead of printing it?

Comment: For the record: `println` also returns something for you (`nil`); but
you most likely experience the side-effect here.

Answer (score 9):

You even don't have to use `str`- just write your string as the last expression to evaluate.

Note that Clojure has functions [`even?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/even_q) and [`odd?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/odd_q):

```
(defn even-or-odd [number]
  (if (odd? number)
   "Odd"
   "Even"))
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd be tempted to make sure we were dealing with an integer:

```
(defn even-or-odd? [x]
  (when (integer? x)
    (if (even? x) "Even" "Odd")))

(map even-or-odd? [\x 1 2 1.3])
=> (nil "Odd" "Even" nil)
```

... rather than risk an exception:

```
(even? 1.3)

Execution error (IllegalArgumentException) ... .
Argument must be an integer: 1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.

````
(defn even-or-odd [number]
  ; ...
   (if (= (Math/abs (rem number 2)) 1)
    (str "Odd")
    (str "Even"))
)```
````